# Can't pass data to mat-table

Tags: json, angular, angular-material

I'm creating Heroes 3 database and I can't pass my data to table. I can see the data via console.log, so I think the problem is not with the service.

Here's my service

```
export class FactionsService {
  castleBuildingsUrl = 'assets/buildings/castleBuildings.json';
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getCastleBuildings(): Observable<Buildings[]> {
    return this.http.get<Buildings[]>(`${this.castleBuildingsUrl}`);
  }
}
```

my ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { FactionsService } from '../../../../services/factions.service';
import { Buildings } from '../../../../models/buildings.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-castlebuildings',
  templateUrl: './castlebuildings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./castlebuildings.component.scss'],
})
export class CastleBuildingsComponent implements OnInit {
  buildings: Buildings[] = [];
  dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<Buildings>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'structure',
    'cost',
    'requirements',
    'benefits',
  ];
  constructor(private factionsService: FactionsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCastleBuildings();
  }

  getCastleBuildings() {
    this.factionsService.getCastleBuildings().subscribe((data: Buildings[]) => {
      console.log('Received data:', data);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Buildings>(data);
    });
  }
}
```

html

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="dataSource">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="structure">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Structure</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let buildings">
        {{ buildings.structure }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="cost">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Cost</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let buildings">{{ buildings.cost }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="requirements">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Requirements</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let buildings">{{ buildings.requirements }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="benefits">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Benefits</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let buildings">{{ buildings.benefits }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

interface

```
export interface Buildings {
  structure: string;
  cost: string;
  requirements: string;
  benefits: string;
}
```

and just in case a fragment of json data

```
{
  "buildings": [
    {
      "structure": "Village Hall",
      "cost": "N/A",
      "requirements": "none",
      "benefits": "Automatically a part of all towns; provides an income of 500 gold per day"
    },
    {
      "structure": "Town Hall",
      "cost": "2500 gold",
      "requirements": "Village Hall, Tavern",
      "benefits": "Provides 1000 gold per day"
    },
    {
      "structure": "City Hall",
      "cost": "5000 gold",
      "requirements": "Town Hall, Blacksmith, Mage Guild Level 1, Marketplace",
      "benefits": "Provides 2000 gold per day"
    },
```

I think everything should be fine and honestly I don't know what am I missing. This is my first post here and I'm beginner with programming, so please be gentle :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, problem solved. I changed a little bit my .ts code and works like a charm

```
getCastleBuildings() {
this.factionsService.getCastleBuildings().subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Buildings>(response.buildings);
});
```

}